# Fourier Transform (DTFT, CTFT) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have to compute Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform for a signal and plot its graphs (magnitude and phase).

[image]

How to do this in Matlab? As I know Matlab provides built in function `fft` which computes DFT and probably it is possible to convert results from DFT to DTFT. I found function that get DTFT using `fft` inside.

```
function [H, W] = dtft(h, N)
%DTFT   calculate DTFT at N equally spaced frequencies
%----
%   Usage:   [H, W] = dtft(h, N)
%
%      h : finite-length input vector, whose length is L
%      N : number of frequencies for evaluation over [-pi,pi)
%              ==> constraint: N >= L 
%      H : DTFT values (complex)
%      W : (2nd output) vector of freqs where DTFT is computed

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% copyright 1994, by C.S. Burrus, J.H. McClellan, A.V. Oppenheim,
% T.W. Parks, R.W. Schafer, & H.W. Schussler.  For use with the book
% "Computer-Based Exercises for Signal Processing Using MATLAB"
% (Prentice-Hall, 1994).
%---------------------------------------------------------------

N = fix(N);
L = length(h);  h = h(:);  %<-- for vectors ONLY !!!
if( N < L )
   error('DTFT: # data samples cannot exceed # freq samples')
end;
W = (2 * pi / N) * (0:(N-1))';
mid = ceil(N/2) + 1;
W(mid:N) = W(mid:N) - 2 * pi;   % <--- move [pi,2pi) to [-pi,0)
W = fftshift(W);
H = fftshift(fft(h,N));  %<--- move negative freq components
end
```

Could you please help me to change this function to get IDTFT? Or maybe someone has other similar functions to do this task.

Comment: By the way, the mathematical expressions in the beginning of your question are the definition of the Fourier Transform and its inverse. These are neither DFT nor DTFT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDTFT should be a simple integral, so you can do this:

```
X_r = ifft(ifftshift(X_w))
```

#### Example

Let's check this with a simple sine wave:

```
%// Generate input signal
t = linspace(0, 10, 1000);
x = sin(2 * pi * t);

%// Compute DTFT and IDTFT
[X_w, F] = dtft(x, 1000);   %// DTFT
X_r = ifft(ifftshift(X_w)); %// IDTFT

%// Plot the result
figure
subplot(2, 1, 1), plot(t, x)
subplot(2, 1, 2), plot(t, X_r)
```

This should yield the following plot:

[image]